# Was Joule's experiment able to show: thermal energy = $mgh$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

Is my understanding of this [experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equivalent_of_heat) correct?
There is the quantity $MC\delta \theta$ associated to the heat which I think is not an absolute value to be compared with $mgh$ since the $\delta \theta$ could be defined arbitrarily. So this experiment does not prove : thermal energy  = $mgh$ it could however show a linear relation between $\delta \theta$ and $h$.

Comment: Hi richard, can you include more information about the experiment in question?  A short description and a link maybe?

Comment: Hi Brandon, I just added the link

Answer (score 2):

The experiment you link is Joule's classic paddle-wheel experiment.
[image]
Specifically, Joule determined that applying 772.24 foot pound force via the weight produced a rise of 1 degree F in one pound of water, although later, more precise experiments gave slightly higher numbers.

The experiment is described in exhaustive detail in Joule's paper, a copy of which can be found here https://books.google.com/books?id=J0fCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=joule's+mechanical+equivalent+heat+experiment&source=bl&ots=Oxg12Od14h&sig=fdNNgYzOY8iSjrllP4qyyu2ujTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yySfVbunOsybNp7Ei-gJ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=joule's%20mechanical%20equivalent%20heat%20experiment&f=false

A few notes: There were 2 weights, not one, with a total weight of 582 pounds, and the vertical travel for the weights was more than 10 feet (measured to .02 inch resolution). Temperature was measured to hundredths of a degree F.

Joule's original finding was not expressed in terms of mgh. Rather, it was in foot pounds force (pounds of force x fall in feet). Nor was the specific heat of water the only variable, since the water was contained in a copper vessel, and Joule made scrupulous corrections for the specific heat of copper versus water.

So, did Joule's experiment establish the equivalence of mechanical work and thermal energy? You suggest that "There is the quantity MCδθ  associated to the heat which I think is not an absolute value to be compared with mgh  since the δθ  could be defined arbitrarily." While that is true (temperature measurement uses quite arbitrary units based on the behavior of water, alcohol and mercury) it misses the point. What Joule's experiment did was to establish quantitative, rather than relative, values for C, the specific heat. Specific heat has the units of energy per unit temperature. Until Joule (or perhaps von Mayer), there was simply no way to quantify the relationship. In establishing the value, Joule established the principle - or vice versa, if you prefer.

Joule's work was originally met with rather deafening silence, but with repeated experiments his findings were eventually accepted. Along the way he butted heads with Julius Robert von Mayer, who had published an equivalent finding nearly a year before Joule, but eventually the honors went to Joule.

Answer (score 1):

The experiment was designed to show that a mechanical process (a paddle wheel stirring water) could cause the water temperature to rise by a predictable amount. The equivalence was tested by using a system in which the mechanical work could be easily measured, a mass falling in a gravitational field.

It turns out that there are several linear relationships in this experiment because of the way that Joule designed the experiment, but $\delta\theta \propto \delta h$ is not a fundamental physics property.

The experiment was a good first step in showing that mechanical work and heat were both methods of transferring energy from one object to another, and that mechanical work done on a system could end up as a temperature change of the system, and not necessarily macroscopic motion of the system.  The converse of this would be that using a temperature change could cause mechanical motion.

The linear relationship between temperature change and height change is specific to that experiment (and others like it. It is not a universal relationship.

If one lets an object fall a large distance, say from outer space, and get heated due to air resistance, the temperature increase will not be linear with height because the initial frictional resistance is not constant (it depends on speed and atmospheric density) and the gravitational field is not constant.

As another example, consider that a nail will experience an increase in temperature when it is driven into a piece of wood with a hammer. The temperature increase is not linearly proportional to the depth change because the frictional force is not constant along the path.

But the temperatures are increasing due to the energy input to the space rock or the nail by mechanical processes, not due to a temperature disequilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but first of all I think you should consider a variation of $h$ to get the mechanical energy that went into heat:

$m C \delta \theta = mg\delta h$

The linear relation is between $\delta \theta$ and $\delta h$. If you study the coefficient that drives this proportionality relation, you will find that it depends on mass, gravity and heat capacity. When you disassemble this coefficient and write the relation as above you are actually comparing thermal and mechanical energies.